# global name 'display' is not found

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently designing a code for a troubleshooter. My problem is that when I press "other", there should be a data entry form label, which there is. But when i type something into it and press continue, it shows an error that says "

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File"R:\ICT\ControlledAssessment_15_17\Computing\Unit3\RiddhiSharma\FinalTroubleshooter.py", line 15, in click
display.insert(END, key)
NameError: global name 'display' is not defined
```

I think the problem in my actual code is here:

```
def click():
    display.insert(END, key)
    output.delete(0.0, END)
    try:
        entered_text=entry.get()
        definition = my_glossary[entered_text]
    except:
        definition = "There is no entry for this word."
        output.insert(END, definition)
```

Comment: I don't see a `display = ...` anywhere in your code, so it's not surprising to me that `display.insert(...)` would be unable to find the `display` variable.

Comment: You don't need all that code to replicate the problem. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Apparently display is not part of the tkinter module or it is not defined altogether. So when you try to use it, it raises an error because you have not defined display as a variable, function, class etc. So define display is a function that takes two arguments, END and key.

When defining display. You could do something like this:

```
display = 123
```

You could also make it a ENTRY, or whatever display is supposed to be. In your case, display doesn't have to be equal to 123. It could be equal to a class:

```
display = Display()
```

Just define Display() first... but display can be anything you want, as long you define it and use it correctly.

Comment: Looking at this line, `display.insert(END, key)`, display is supposed to be an `Entry` or something like that.

Comment: I tried the display = 123 and now it says AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

Answer (score 0):

@PythonMaster thanks a lot for your help. To solve my problem I replaced the display function and wrote the code out like this:

```
    def click():
        entered_text = entry.get()
        output.delete(0.0, END)
    try:
        definition = my_glossary[entered_text]
    except:
        definition = "There is no entry for this word."
    output.insert(END, definition)
```